# Doubling the number of backslashes with different flavors of `awk`

Tags: awk

I'm looking for a portable way to backslash-escape the backslashes in a string with `awk`.

For example, with GNU & BSD you would write:

```bash
echo '\ \\ \\\' | command -p awk '{gsub(/\\/,"\\\\"); print}'
```

But on other NIXes you would have to write:

```bash
echo '\ \\ \\\' | command -p awk '{gsub(/\\/,"\\\\\\\\"); print}'
```

---

If you don't have access to AIX/HP-UX/Solaris/etc..., I think that the problem could be emulated with GNU/BSD `awk` in this way:

```bash
echo '\ \\ \\\' | awk '{gsub(/\\/, ... ); print}'

echo '\ \\ \\\' | awk --posix '{gsub(/\\/, ... ); print}'
```

where `...` is the same for both commands; both should yield:

```
\\ \\\\ \\\\\\
```

Comment: have you considered the `FS` way on Solaris ? :::::::: `printf '%s' '\ \\ \\\' | gawk --posix NF=NF FS='\\' OFS='\\\\' ; printf '%s' '\ \\ \\\' | gawk NF=NF FS='\\' OFS='\\\\'` ::::::::::: `'\\ \\\\ \\\\\\'` :::::::::: `'\\ \\\\ \\\\\\'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `awk` command should be portable:

```bash
echo '\ \\ \\\' | awk '{gsub(/\\/, "&&")} 1'
```

Where `&` represents complete matched string using the regex pattern used i.e. `/\\/`.

Comment: Yes, that works! I'm getting a weird result on Solaris though, I'm investigating the issue.

Comment: I think there's a bug in Solaris's libc. `sed 's/\\/\\\\/g'` and `perl -pe 's/\\/\\\\/g'` both output ```\\ \\ \\\\```

Answer (score 2):

This works in gawk and any POSIX compliant awk:

```
$ echo '\ \\ \\\' | gawk '{gsub(/\\/,"\\\\&"); print}'
\\ \\\\ \\\\\\

$ echo '\ \\ \\\' | gawk --posix '{gsub(/\\/,"\\\\&"); print}'
\\ \\\\ \\\\\\
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Gory-Details for why there's a difference between POSIX and gawks default behavior with some series of backslashes in this context and in particular tables 9.2 (gawk) and 9.3 (POSIX) both showing that:

```
You type         sub() sees         sub() generates
\\\\&            \\&            A literal ‘\’, followed by the matched text
```

as used in the above `sub()`s will escape a string in POSIX and GNU awk.

Note that the above is how to escape any matched string, not just how to escape `\`:

```
$ echo 'X XX XXX' | gawk '{gsub(/X/,"\\\\&"); print}'
\X \X\X \X\X\X

$ echo 'X XX XXX' | gawk --posix '{gsub(/X/,"\\\\&"); print}'
\X \X\X \X\X\X

$ echo '[ [[ [[[' | gawk '{gsub(/\[/,"\\\\&"); print}'
\[ \[\[ \[\[\[

$ echo '[ [[ [[[' | gawk --posix '{gsub(/\[/,"\\\\&"); print}'
\[ \[\[ \[\[\[
```

Comment: Thanks, that might prove useful

Answer (score 2):

`Awk` is innocent here, `echo` is incompatible between platforms. The compatible version of `echo` is `printf`. Try this:

```
printf '%s\n' '\ \\ \\\'  | /usr/bin/awk '{gsub(/\\/,"\\\\"); print}'
```

or this:

```
printf '\\ \\\\ \\\\\\\n' | /usr/bin/awk '{gsub(/\\/,"\\\\"); print}'
```

Comment: Fair point; that was the problem with Solaris. I don't understand why though, the shell is bash-5.1 so echo shouldn't do anything with the backslashes o_O

Comment: Echo can be a builtin or a standalone program (on Aix, there might be an /usr/ucb/echo which is incompatible with /usr/bin/echo); /bin/sh is can be dash, bash, ksh. You can create a test-script to examine the combination.

Answer (score 1):

i can't say with 100% certainty whether this works on whacko fringe that is `Solaris` or `busybox` `awk`, but my own module does it like :

> ```
> gsub("[\\\\^]", "\\\\&", str)
> ```

for escaping both `\\` and `\^` :

```
 for __ in nawk       mawk1      mawk2     'gawk -e' 
          'gawk -Pe' 'gawk -ce' 'gawk -re' 'gawk -se' 
          'gawk -ne' 'gawk -Se' 'gawk -Me' 'gawk -MPe'; do 

    echo " $__ |::::| $( printf '%s' '\\ \\\\ \\\\\\' |
```

---

```
    $( printf '%s' "$__" ) '  # either one of ::

    function ___(__,_) { 

        return substr(_ = "\\\\",
                 gsub("["_ "^]",_ "&",__),_)__

    } function ____(_) { 

        return substr("", gsub(/[\\^]/, "\\\\&",_))_
    } 
    ($++NF = ___($!_))^_' FS='\n' OFS=' | '
```

---

```
 )"; done | column -s'|' -t

 nawk        ::::   \ \\ \\\    \\ \\\\ \\\\\\
 mawk1       ::::   \ \\ \\\    \\ \\\\ \\\\\\
 mawk2       ::::   \ \\ \\\    \\ \\\\ \\\\\\

 gawk -e     ::::   \ \\ \\\    \\ \\\\ \\\\\\
 gawk -Pe    ::::   \ \\ \\\    \\ \\\\ \\\\\\
 gawk -ce    ::::   \ \\ \\\    \\ \\\\ \\\\\\

 gawk -re    ::::   \ \\ \\\    \\ \\\\ \\\\\\
 gawk -se    ::::   \ \\ \\\    \\ \\\\ \\\\\\
 gawk -ne    ::::   \ \\ \\\    \\ \\\\ \\\\\\

 gawk -Se    ::::   \ \\ \\\    \\ \\\\ \\\\\\
 gawk -Me    ::::   \ \\ \\\    \\ \\\\ \\\\\\
 gawk -MPe   ::::   \ \\ \\\    \\ \\\\ \\\\\\
```